# Print 4 slides per page - automation

Tags: graphics

I need a script that uses `includegraphics` or similar to put pages 1-4 of **input.pdf** on page 1 on *output.pdf* If, then, the **input**.pdf has page 5-8 then I want to put that on page 2 in *output.pdf*.

After some searching I found the code

```
\includepdf[pages={1-4},scale=0.75]{bplot.pdf} % some pages. each pdf page fill a page...
```

But I do not know how to automate it so allow for varying sizes of the input.pdf

---

The reason is that I'm creating a script for printing using Apple's built in program "automator". I have thus far done it so that I can move a file to a folder /printingauto, and then the following is done automatically

1. Print the file
2. Append _printed_todaysdate in the file name
3. Move to subfolder /printingauto/printed

What I would like to do now is to set up a folder that, as a first step, do the above mention latex task so that I can print a document on 4 pages to save paper.

My idea is that once I have the latex text, be able to (1) highlight a pdf in finder (2) extract the name of the pdf (3) create a .tex file inside the directory (4) paste in the latex text and render, (5) mode that pdf to /printingauto.

Comment: I think you're overcomplicating this...

Comment: try `\includepdf[nup=2x2,pages={1-4},scale=0.75]{bplot.pdf}`

Comment: `psnup`? http://www.peppertop.com/blog/?p=35

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your question, you don't need external scripts to achieve the same result.

So let's say you have a PDF consisting of 25 pages. I started a loop using `\foreach` that iterates each page and wraps it in a `\minipage`. Every 4 pages, it will insert a `\newpage` using modular arithmetic.

The only thing I didn't manage to do is to make the lower the same as the upper white space, hopefully someone can weigh in on that.

I used a pdf of mine to show the preview, so this code won't work out of the box in your computer. Just replace the name of the file to include.

### Output

<sup>*Partial preview*</sup>

[image]

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{pgffor}

\begin{document}
{\setlength\parindent{0cm}
\foreach \x in {1,...,25}{%
\pgfmathsetmacro\switch{int(mod(\x,5))}
    \ifnum\switch=0
        \newpage
    \else
        \vspace*{\fill}
        \begin{minipage}{.49\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[page=\x, scale=.75]{prova8.pdf}
        \end{minipage}\hfill%
    \fi
}}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes, this is good! Can you make it create less (or no) space in the corners?

Comment: @user1603548 Mmh can you explain what you mean? Sorry, I don't understand.

Comment: Maybe `\usepackage[margin=0cm]{geometry}` will do what I want.

Comment: @user1603548 Ah that. Yes, that will reduce the margins to 0, but make sure the printer can print that wide.